# Extracting specific rows from a nested data frame using map with an if else condition

Tags: r, purrr

I have a data frame with some nested data and I would like to flatten the data and extract specific cells from the nested data.

The nested data is in the column `MetaData` which looks like the following:

```
[[1]]
      Id Variable.Id        Variable.Nombre Variable.Codigo                     Nombre Codigo
1     72           3           Tipo de dato                                  Dato base       
2   5457          19             Municipios             MUN                     Abrera  08001
3 274520         260 Conceptos Demográficos                 Edad media de la población       

[[2]]
      Id Variable.Id        Variable.Nombre Variable.Codigo                              Nombre  Codigo
1     72           3           Tipo de dato                                           Dato base        
2 366833         260 Conceptos Demográficos                 Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales        
3 327739         846              Distritos            DIST                Badalona distrito 02 0801502

[[3]]
      Id Variable.Id        Variable.Nombre Variable.Codigo                                 Nombre     Codigo
1     72           3           Tipo de dato                                              Dato base           
2 366833         260 Conceptos Demográficos                    Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales           
3 331103         847              Secciones            SECC Santa Coloma de Gramenet sección 05009 0824505009
```

I want to extract -

- From `[[1]]` the `municipios`, `MUN`, `Abrera` and `08001`
- From `[[2]]` the `Distritos`, `DIST`, `Badalona distrito 02` and `0801502`
- From `[[3]]` the `Secciones`, `SECC`, `Santa Columa de Gramenet sección 05009` and `0824505009`.

However, just using the cell location does not work since the location for the `MUN` data is in a slightly different location for the `DIST` and `SECC` data - i.e. for `MUN` under the column `Nombre` and `Codigo` the cell location is in row 2, whereas for the `DIST` and `SECC` data the cell location is in row 3.

I have the following code which can extract the data for the `MUN` without problem.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(MetaDataWider = map(MetaData, ~ {
    v1 <- .x[cbind(c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3), c(3, 3, 4, 5, 5))]
    names(v1) <- c("type", "contable", "type_code", "region", "variable")
    as_tibble_row(v1)
  })
  )
```

I now want to add an `ifelse` statement to the `map`/`map_if` in order to correctly extract the data for the `DIST` and `SECC` observations.

Alternatively, create the `ifelse` statment to change the order of the `DIST` and `SECC` observations. i.e.

> if `Variable.Codigo` contains `DIST` | `SECC` shift row 3 to row 2,
> else nothing.

Then I can use the code I already have to extract the data.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(COD = c("ADRH7218704", "ADRH7013747", "ADRH6909920"
), Nombre = c("Abrera. Edad media de la población. Dato base. ", 
"Badalona distrito 02. Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales. Dato base. ", 
"Santa Coloma de Gramenet sección 05009. Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales. Dato base. "
), T3_Unidad = c("Años", "Porcentaje", "Porcentaje"), T3_Escala = c(" ", 
" ", " "), MetaData = list(structure(list(Id = c(72L, 5457L, 
274520L), Variable = structure(list(Id = c(3L, 19L, 260L), Nombre = c("Tipo de dato", 
"Municipios", "Conceptos Demográficos"), Codigo = c("", "MUN", 
"")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), Nombre = c("Dato base", 
"Abrera", "Edad media de la población"), Codigo = c("", "08001", 
"")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), structure(list(
    Id = c(72L, 366833L, 327739L), Variable = structure(list(
        Id = c(3L, 260L, 846L), Nombre = c("Tipo de dato", "Conceptos Demográficos", 
        "Distritos"), Codigo = c("", "", "DIST")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L)), Nombre = c("Dato base", "Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales", 
    "Badalona distrito 02"), Codigo = c("", "", "0801502")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L)), structure(list(Id = c(72L, 366833L, 331103L), Variable = structure(list(
    Id = c(3L, 260L, 847L), Nombre = c("Tipo de dato", "Conceptos Demográficos", 
    "Secciones"), Codigo = c("", "", "SECC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L)), Nombre = c("Dato base", "Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales", 
"Santa Coloma de Gramenet sección 05009"), Codigo = c("", "", 
"0824505009")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L))), 
    Data = list(structure(list(Fecha = c("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", 
    "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", 
    "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"), T3_TipoDato = c("Definitivo", 
    "Definitivo", "Definitivo", "Definitivo"), T3_Periodo = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A"), Anyo = 2018:2015, Valor = c(39.7, 39.5, 39.2, 
    38.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L)), structure(list(
        Fecha = c("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", 
        "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"
        ), T3_TipoDato = c("Definitivo", "Definitivo", "Definitivo", 
        "Definitivo"), T3_Periodo = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), Anyo = 2018:2015, 
        Valor = c(25.5, 25.7, 25.5, 25.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    4L)), structure(list(Fecha = c("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", 
    "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", 
    "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"), T3_TipoDato = c("Definitivo", 
    "Definitivo", "Definitivo", "Definitivo"), T3_Periodo = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A"), Anyo = 2018:2015, Valor = c(24.1, 23.6, 22.2, 
    20.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L)))), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `purrr::map_df` ?

```
purrr::map_df(data$MetaData, ~ {
  .x[.x$Variable$Codigo != '', ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I would also like to get the data under the column `Nombre`. i.e. the following `Edad media de la población`, `Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales` and `Porcentaje de hogares unipersonales` - it always appears in the same row as `Conceptos Demográficos` under the column `Variable.Nombre`.

Comment: Use `bind_cols` to add them as column - `bind_cols(Num = data$Nombre, purrr::map_df(data$MetaData, ~ .x[.x$Variable$Codigo != '', ]))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(data$MetaData, function(x) {
                     do.call(data.frame, subset(x, Variable$Codigo != ""))
       }))
```

-output

```
  Id Variable.Id Variable.Nombre Variable.Codigo                                 Nombre     Codigo
1:   5457          19      Municipios             MUN                                 Abrera      08001
2: 327739         846       Distritos            DIST                   Badalona distrito 02    0801502
3: 331103         847       Secciones            SECC Santa Coloma de Gramenet sección 05009 0824505009
```